# Virtual Assistant in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a virtual assistant in Python, but I want it the more "human" possible. I want her to interpret my question, not compare with an string.
So, my doubt is:

To cover all variations of the same request, like "Will rain tomorrow?" and "Tomorrow I'll need an umbrella?" I have to put each request in an If statement?
For example:

```
if audio == "Will rain tomorrow?":
    checkWeather()...

if audio == "Tomorrow I'll need an umbrella?":
    checkWeather()...

another if statements...
```

This is the way that the great virtual assistants (Siri, Google Now, etc) are coded or is there a method to cover the variations without repeating a condition statement for every possibility? Is a technique for modeling the code or something that I need to know?

Comment: Siri and Google Now are very complicated software and they are certainly not just a big bunch of if statements. They involve cutting-edge natural language parsing and artificial intelligence, which are way too broad topics to cover here.

Comment: You answer doesn't help at all. Can you discuss about this cutting-edge natural language parsing? About the artificial intelligence? I don't want a copy of this virtual assistants, I want improve the one that I'm making.

Comment: You asked if this is how Siri and Google Now work, and I answered that exact question. How does that not help at all?

Comment: You grabed the tiniest doubt of my entire question and answered it, without giving a response to keep the conversation going and show me the way for studying. If you know how Siri and Google Now works, what I'm asking is how they work, which techniques they use, so I can continue sutdying this topics to apply in my virtual assistant.

Comment: Yes, that is how comments work – if I had an answer to the entire question, I would have written an answer. You can google those topics as well as I can.

Comment: maybe take a look at this, has some interesting topics you can study: http://xrds.acm.org/blog/2017/01/build-natural-language-processing-based-intelligent-assistant-using-python-easy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is take a look at [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) and learn about natural language processing. Learn about tokenization and tagging and I think you may get somewhere.

This link might have some interesting topics:

http://xrds.acm.org/blog/2017/01/build-natural-language-processing-based-intelligent-assistant-using-python-easy/

But be aware that what you are trying to do is not an easy task!

Comment: This is an efficient answer. You understood that I needed a name of a technique to study, and gave it to me.
Thanks a lot.